# Windows authentication without login prompt in .net core 3.0. Application is hosted in IIS

Tags: windows-authentication, asp.net-core-3.0

I am using .net core 3.0. I want to do windows authentication without login prompt. Application is hosted in IIS.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Would you mind showing us what you have tried so that we can help you to fix the issues  you have with that? If you haven't tried anything, please check [this](https://www.google.se/search?safe=active&ei=GnwdXrX8H8eFmwWBlKyoBw&q=windows+authentication+asp.net+core+3&oq=windows+authentication+asp.net+core+3) page.

Answer (score 0):

The site will be in the intranet zone. it should not be like www.xxx.com.
It should be like http://servername:port(like 8080)